# Python: How to open map created with folium in browser when running application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very small application written in PyCharm using python3:

```
import folium

map = folium.Map(location=[58.1, 23.3], zoom_start=10)
map.save('map2.html')
```

This will create a `map2.html` which I can access in my browser by using pycharm and the url looks like: http://localhost:63342/iss-country/map2.html?_ijt=dcsefdg8om4ddfovlt5ooq6ro5

How can I automatically open this in my browser? So when I run the application it does not only generate the html page but also visits it immediatley. I found the `webbrowser` module which can be useful but how do I know the correct localhost url?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the issue with using the [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module. Just make the file name and path a variable and call the webbrowser open method.

```
output_file = "map2.html"
map = folium.Map(location=[58.1, 23.3], zoom_start=10)
map.save(output_file)
webbrowser.open(output_file, new=2)  # open in new tab
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try this:

```
my_map.show_in_browser()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
webbrowser.open("http://localhost:80/"+output_file, new=2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.