# Dataframe object is not callable in geopandas

Tags: python, dataframe, geojson, geopandas

I have a dataset contains latitude longitude Temp
I tried to draw a contour map of temp based on latitude and longitude on the world map. I need to mark the contour line intervals also in the map.
I tried the below code got from a similar question.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
Import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

Data=pd.read_csv("df.txt")
Data1=Dataframe.to_csv('sample.csv', index=None)
Sample=pd read_csv('sample.csv',delim_whitspace=True)
temp = sample['temp']
lon = sample['lon']
lat = sample['lat']

y = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
x = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lat, lon), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
contour =    plt.contour(X,Y, Z)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(sample(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
    contour=contour,
    min_angle_deg=3.0,
    ndigits=5,
    stroke_width=1))).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

m = gdf.explore(color=gdf["stroke"])

plt.show()
m
```

I'm getting an error ' Dataframe object is not callable'
How can I solve the issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple syntax and semantic errors. See comments in fixed code below.

Fundamentally the error *Dataframe object is not callable* Makes no sense to use a dataframe object to convert a JSON encoded string to JSON using an data frame object. Clearly you want to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
# Import pandas as pd # import with a capital !!!
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

# let's create a file as it doesn't exist on any system other than OP
with open("df.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""lat,lon,temp
34.355,141.6211,11.116286876289658
-17.7691,-178.312,7.952002019397204
-6.5982,147.3301,24.62322868970752
50.954,-179.2585,11.71324100350295
11.9822,-87.1375,15.01789103393663
-33.2708,-71.7855,24.469164363171046
-36.8458,-74.1843,18.256370193874996
32.602,-40.1483,7.677618759312514
13.9702,120.821,21.65741634737647
35.0176667,-118.118,9.308472581594794
-6.038,148.5685,7.303807691740786
-10.9269,162.1543,20.834742114943694
-22.4121,-67.3461,22.421598068428683
-5.8357,128.9122,23.48156402329026
61.3715,-150.045,13.103182072669588
51.7784,-173.9138,7.828683632233058
-2.5579,99.5117,12.704418487583837
-14.4739,-13.3795,21.39126818102271
18.697,-68.0025,19.162216173098656
36.2098333,-117.856,8.162743541290157""")

Data=pd.read_csv("df.txt")
## very odd
# Data1=Dataframe.to_csv('sample.csv', index=None)
Data1=Data.to_csv('sample.csv', index=None)
# Sample=pd read_csv('sample.csv',delim_whitspace=True) 
## 1. pd<space>read_csv!!!
## 2. unpercase Sample when following lines are lowercase
## 3. invalid parameter delim_whitspace=True
sample=pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
# temp = pd.cut(sample['temp'], bins=5, labels=range(5)).astype(int)
temp = sample["temp"]
lon = sample['lon']
lat = sample['lat']

y = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
x = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lat, lon), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
contour =    plt.contour(X,Y, Z)

## sample is a dataframe object, so why would you use it to convert a string encoding of JSON to JSON?
# gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(sample(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
#     contour=contour,
#     min_angle_deg=3.0,
#     ndigits=5,
#     stroke_width=1))).set_crs("EPSG:4326")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(json.loads(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
    contour=contour,
    min_angle_deg=3.0,
    ndigits=5,
    stroke_width=1))).set_crs("EPSG:4326")


m = gdf.explore(color=gdf["stroke"])

plt.show()
m
```

#### open map in tab

You have not stated you environment.  [Python: How to open map created with folium in browser when running application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069033/python-how-to-open-map-created-with-folium-in-browser-when-running-application)

If you are running in Jupyter,  the map will just have displayed.

```
from pathlib import Path
import webbrowser
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("map.html")
m.save(str(f))
webbrowser.open(str(f), new=2)
```

#### intervals

assume you mean bins.... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Hence if you just want to consider 5 bands of temperature

```
temp = pd.cut(sample['temp'], bins=5, labels=range(5)).astype(int)
```

Comment: don't know what happened to your comment,  but really it's changing scope of question.  You asked about why you had a specific error which is really the answer

Comment: Yes.. I'm getting key error in the Temp
My data have float values as Temp.. I tried to edit that's why I changed.

Comment: I used my data and tried ...I'm getting the contour plot on other latitude and longitude. That's not the latitude and longitude of the country in the dataset.The output showing large contour lines somewhere else   I'm not telling about the bins. It's like marking each temp on related contour lines. Please give me a solution!!

Comment: I'm getting some large contour lines on the upper middle of world map. I just need to mark the temp on correct latitude and longitude. How can I Mark the temp on correct latitude and longitude of the map and make it some fixed zoom of that country!!!

Comment: Yes .. that's my question but the contour lines is present in the upper middle of map... that's not my latitude and longitude....How can I solve that issue!!!

Comment: look at the other question - I've reworked it.  take a look at this doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata.  as I stated in other question have changed to use linear.  Is my answer so poor it's not clear it's been changed?.  I'll give it 10 m ins and delete all answers as they are obviously very bad

Comment: I clear about those ...but why those contour lines marking somewhere else that not in my longitude and latitude data. My data is like a column with whitespace seperated and example lat as 5.00 lon as 40.00 and Temp as 283.91...  Please help to solve the issue!!

Comment: I can't add data or images because I'm a beginner in this community. A data lat and after 3 whitespace lon and after 4 whitespace Temp. I didn't change anything I used my data and didn't used that with open file section ( create data section)

Comment: one last try.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70720811/contour-plot-using-folium-in-pycharm/70739846#70739846 has a good answer and it's your question too...  could you PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE help me help you by looking at it?  Do you have base knowledge of interpolation - if not that's ok.  but at least try **linear** instead of **cubic**.  Clearly it's easy to make errors, as demonstrated by this question - e.g `Import` which is not even a valid python keyword