# Folium map not getting displayed

Tags: python, folium

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium as fo

data = pd.read_csv("...")

lat = list(data["Latitude"])
lon = list(data["Longitude"])
name = list(data["Name"])

volcano = fo.FeatureGroup(name="Volcano")
for a, b, c in zip(lat, lon, name):
    volcano.add_child(fo.Marker(location=[a, b], popup=c, icon=fo.Icon(color='blue')))
    
fo.Map().add_child(volcano)
```

**END**

The output should be a map with markers on it opened in a browser. But in this case, the map isn't getting displayed on the browser. Any solutions to fix it ?

Comment: A [mcve] without a csv file would help... Check the browser console; any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium as fo


m = fo.Map()




data = pd.read_csv("...")

lat = list(data["Latitude"])
lon = list(data["Longitude"])
name = list(data["Name"])

volcano = fo.FeatureGroup(name="Volcano")
for a, b, c in zip(lat, lon, name):
    volcano.add_child(fo.Marker(location=[a, b], popup=c, icon=fo.Icon(color='blue')))
    
m.add_child(volcano)

m # to show the map
```

Edit:

The former would work in a `jupyter-notebook`.

For showing the map in a browser window:

```
output_file = "map_volacno.html"
map.save(output_file)
webbrowser.open(output_file, new=2)  # open in new tab
```

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56655444/3957794).

Comment: Same problem. Graph does appear in the web browser. As I am expecting that map will be displayed in the browser but no new windows are prompted open after executing the command.

Comment: Updated answer: folium is based on the web-browser.